# How do I change the labels on my pie chart (df.plot)

Tags: python, pie-chart

I'm using the df.plot function and trying to plot a graph but im not sure how to change the labels on my pie chart from numbers (index values) to the values from my csv file
Also if you could please help me hid the index values in my table as i only wish to display the rank so the index values are unnecessary.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qDuU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ljdw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/060fu.png)

```
df=pd.read_csv("top_10_states_2020.csv")
print("Pie Chart => Top 10 most visited states of India by foreign tourists (in 2020)")
print(df)
df.plot(kind="pie", x="State/UT", y="No. of tourists", )
plt.xlabel("Destination")
plt.ylabel("No. of tourists")
plt.title("Top 10 most visited states of India by foreign tourists (in 2020)")
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

I expected to see the names of the various locations however all i see are the index values

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for sharing the code instead of image, (it helps a lot).
I see what the issue is. My humble suggestion is to extract the labels from your dataframe by using this line of code:

```
labels = df['State/UT'].values
```

and then, you just have to modify the plot line:

```
df.plot(kind="pie", x="State/UT", y="No. of tourists", )
```

With a slightly modified version:

```
df.plot(kind="pie", y="No. of tourists", labels=labels)
```

I believe it is going to do what you wanted.

Good luck!